# MSBuild inline task reference is escaping parenthesis, sometimes

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I am writing an inline task for MSBuild.  It requires a reference to `System.ServiceProcess.dll`.

The task works great if I hard-code the path to the System.ServiceProcess.dll file, like this:

```
<UsingTask
    TaskName="MyTask"
    TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory"
    AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
    <Task>
        <Reference Include="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.ServiceProcess.dll" />
        <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">...working fine...</Code>
    </Task>
</UsingTask>
```

However, I would rather not hard-code that path.

If I just use `<Reference Include="System.ServiceProcess.dll" />`, I get an error: `MSB3755: Could not find reference "System.ServiceProcess.dll"`, so I think I have to use the full path here.

The `$(FrameworkPathOverride)` property contains the correct path already, so I tried to use that:

```
<Reference Include="$(FrameworkPathOverride)\System.ServiceProcess.dll" />
```

But that gives me an error:

> C:\path\to\project.csproj(93,3): error MSB3754: The reference assembly "C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.ServiceProcess.dll" is invalid. "The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)"[C:\path\to\project.csproj]

Notice how it escaped `(x86)` into `%28x86%29`.

Notably, it seems to do this only for `$(FrameworkPathOverride)`.  If I define my own property and use it instead, it works just fine, unless that property also references `$(FrameworkPathOverride)`.  In other words, this works (but still has me hard-coding the path):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MyPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5</MyPath>
</PropertyGroup>

// (later, inside <Task />)
<References Include="$(MyPath)\System.ServiceProcess.dll" />
```

However, this fails with the same error that reports searching a path for `%28x86%29`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MyPath>$(FrameworkPathOverride)</MyPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Just for kicks, I also tried this variation, which also fails with the same error:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MyPath>$([System.Convert]::ToString("$(FrameworkPathOverride)"))</MyPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Also, in all cases, the output of `<Message Text="$(FrameworkPathOverride)" />` and `<Message Test="$(MyPath)" />` are identical.  The `<Message />` task is *not* escaping the parenthesis inside `$(FrameworkPathOverride)`, but the `<Reference Include="..." />` *is*.  Hmm.

Why does `(x86)` become `%28x86%29` inside `<Reference />` but not inside `<Message />`?

Why does it happen for `$(FrameworkPathOverride)` and not for `$(MyPath)`?

Why does it start happening to `$(MyPath)` if it references `$(FrameworkPathOverride)`?

How can I avoid hard-coding this path?

Comment: I can't get even a hard-coded path to work. I have it like `<Reference Include="$(SolutionDir)ImageTextWriter\bin\$(Configuration)\ImageTextWriter.dll" />` in my Task, but building the project always tells me that it can't find the file. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to your last attempt, have you tried the following using the "Unescape" MSBuild Property Function?

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MyPath>$([MSBuild]::Unescape("$(FrameworkPathOverride)"))</MyPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

It seems to be a known issue titled "MSBuild 4.0 UsingTask cannot have a path with parentheses": http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/532677/msbuild-4-0-usingtask-cannot-have-a-path-with-parentheses

Unfortunately, I have not had the opportunity to test this.

Comment: I had a similar problem and solved it with [MSBuild]::Unescape also.